# Calling one PS script (with a switch parameter) from another PS script using splatting

Tags: powershell

I have the below script

`Untitled2.ps1`:

```
$scriptName = '.\Untitled1.ps1'
$args =  @{
    someVal = "Test"
}
if ($true) {
    $args.testSwitch = $true
}
powershell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File $scriptName @args
```

which calls the script shown below:

`Untitled1.ps1`:

```
[CmdletBinding()]
Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
    [switch]$testSwitch
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
    [string]$someVal
)

$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"
$WarningPreference = "Stop"
Set-PSDebug -Strict -Trace 0

$PSBoundParameters | Out-String
```

However, I get the error message shown below

```
C:\PowershellScripts\Untitled1.ps1 : Cannot process argument transformation
on parameter 'testSwitch'. Cannot convert value "System.String" to type
"System.Management.Automation.SwitchParameter". Boolean parameters accept
only Boolean values and numbers, such as $True, $False, 1 or 0.
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Untitled1.ps1], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentTransformationError,Untitled1.ps1
```

I am not sure exactly what the issue is.
From what I have read you can assign `$true` for a `switch` parameter when splatting using a hashtable.

Comment: You're not calling a ps script, you're calling the ps executable to run the script. If you call the script directly you can use splatting.

Comment: As a side-note: it's not possible that the code you posted produced the error you claim it does, b/c `$args` is an automatic variable that can't be modified like that. Please test your [mcve] before asking a question to make sure the sample code actually exposes the behavior you want to ask about.

Comment: @MikeShepard Splatting isn't the problem here, b/c that's handled by the parent process. However, when the external program is invoked, the boolean argument `$true` is expanded to the string `True` (the statement is mangled into a command string when being passed to the underlying Windows routines). The PowerShell script run in that process would then need to parse the string "True" as a boolean value, but can't. That is what's causing the error. The suggested solution is correct, though: just invoke the script without spawning a second PowerShell process (`& $scriptName @args`).

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers I did try the code prior to posting and it does give me that error message - I am using Powershell 5.1.14409.1012.

Comment: @MikeShepard @AnsgarWichers Yes I just tried invoking directly using the `& $scriptName @args` and it worked.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: It didn't work when I tried it on PowerShell 5.0. Besides, it's practically always a bad idea to use automatic variable like that. Simply rename the variable and the code will work (or rather: fail) just fine.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers I agree.  I am new to Powershell and didn't realize it was a reserved word.